# Recording pressed keys while recording your desktop

Tags: windows-xp, vim, screencasts

What utilities are there that can record and display on screen keys you're pressing and at the same time recording your desktop?

So the viewers can see what keys I'm pressing, for example, while explaining something in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DemoCreator](http://www.sameshow.com/democreator/tutorial/record-screen-activity.html)

It is excellent when it comes to making tutorials, or video demos of software.

Comment: It can show "on screen", so to speak, pressed keys?

Comment: Yes.  Download the trial before you buy it...